# Music keeps running

Tags: android

I have a sound on my app and when I play it and then press the home button, the app keeps running at the background ( I know it because the song keeps going.. ) How can I stop the app and the music?
here's my music code:

```
        SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    int iTmp = sp.load(getBaseContext(), R.raw.windows_8_notify, 1); 
    sp.play(iTmp, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.windows_8_notify);
    mPlayer.start();
    mPlayer.setLooping(true);
    Button btn_show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_popup);
    btn_show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (p != null)
        showPopup(FirstActivity.this, p);
      } }); }
```

Comment: Stop the player in the `onPause()` method of your `Activity`.

Comment: `mPlayer.stop();` not difficult to work out yourself is it?

Answer (score 0):

In your Main Activity just override the onPause method, if you want to restart the music when you re-enter the app, the logic should go into your onResume method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html for more info on the activity class that you must extend to create your android app.

```
class myActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // setup your app here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    // stop or pause your music here
    // other "clean up"
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    // app is now to the forground set things back up that might have been removed in onPause
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stop the player inside the onStop activity callback method

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mPlayer!=null && mPlayer.isPlaying())
        mPlayer.stop();
}
```